How to: Create .jar file for docker-compose while using flyway migration?
I have a Spring Boot app that uses PostgreSQL + Flyway and want to do the following in a docker-compose file:

Generate a .jar file
Run the .jar file
Create a PG database

The problem is that (as far as I know) I need to create the .jar file I need to set the spring.datasource.url property in my application.properties file:
application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cptm  <--- this should be "jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/cptm"
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true

docker-compose.yml
services:
  front:
    image: node:20

  back:
    image: openjdk:17-jdk
    depends_on:
      - db
  
  db: <--- because of this guy
    image: postgres

If I use the property as "localhost" it works fine. However, when I change the "localhost" for "db" in the property, I can not generate the .jar file even through the IntelliJ's "package" command, getting the following error:
com.agnes.cptm.ApplicationTests
SQL State  : 08001
Error Code : 0
Message    : A tentativa de conexão falhou.

    ...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
    ... 58 more

What am I missing here exactly?

It seems like your compile-time tests are trying to use the database.  Can you separate this out so that the compile-time tests can run independently, either mocking your database layer or using an in-memory database like H2 or HDBC, and only use the real database for integration testing?
